# Multiple defined symbols of overloaded operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a Cartesian coords class, where I've attempted to overload some operators, however when building I get a fatal error about how the operator+ has multiple defined symbols.

```
class Cartesian 
public:
        int x,y;

        Cartesian operator/=(const int64_t denominator)
        {
            return { x /= denominator, y /= denominator };
        }

        Cartesian operator+=(const Cartesian& c)
        {
            return { x += c.x, y += c.y };
        }

        Cartesian operator+(const Cartesian& c)
        {
            return { x + c.x, y + c.y };
        }

        friend Cartesian operator+(const Cartesian& c1, const Cartesian& c2);
};

Cartesian operator+(const Cartesian& c1, const Cartesian& c2) { return { c1.x + c2.x, c1.y + c2.y }; };
```

Can someone help identify the mistake I've made here?

Comment: Haha, sounds like a question from a game "can you spot the differences?". Have you tried reading the cide yourself and see the multiple definitions? Hint: it's at the end

Comment: Post the full error message. It'll most likely tell you where you've done it or give you hints. But the problem is that you've defined the operator+ multiple times, but in two different ways. Once as a method and once as a free standing function, but in the end they're the same.

Comment: Why did you define both the free (friend) operator overload and the member operator overload? What did you expect each one to be used for?

Answer (score 1):

This is same operator

```
    Cartesian operator+(const Cartesian& c)
    {
        return { x + c.x, y + c.y };
    }

    friend Cartesian operator+(const Cartesian& c1, const Cartesian& c2);
```

You can have one or another, but not both.
Member operators are assuming that their first operand is one of enclosing class. So both declarations would generate same mangled name. Some 90s compilers could miss that and problem would appear only on linking stage or would not be revealed at all if operator was used, I even had bad luck to acquire a book where sample code contained such mistake.

Comment: In this case, you could just reuse the member `operator+=`, so the out-of-class `operator+` doesn't even need to be befriended. It's usually good to implement methods using existing other methods. Less code duplication=less code to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

[Below](https://onlinegdb.com/3AsU74K_9) is the working example that have overloaded `operator+` for addition and also have overloaded `operator<<` for printing out the current point values. Your mistake was that you were defining `operator+` twice, first inside the class and then outside also. Instead just define it outside the class as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
class Cartesian 
{
    public:
        //Overload operator+ for adding Cartesian instances
        friend Cartesian operator+(const Cartesian& c1, const Cartesian& c2);
        
        //Overload operator<< for printing out Cartesian's x and y values
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Cartesian& obj);
        int x,y;

        void setXY(int px, int py)
        {
            x = px;
            y = py;
        }      
};

Cartesian operator+(const Cartesian& c1, const Cartesian& c2) 
{ 
    return { c1.x + c2.x, c1.y + c2.y };
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Cartesian& obj)
{
    std::cout<<obj.x<<" "<<obj.y;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World"<<std::endl;;
    
    Cartesian point1, point2;
    
    point1.setXY(5,10);
    std::cout<<"point1's coordinates are: "<<point1<<std::endl;
    
    point2.setXY(15, 20);
    std::cout<<"point2's coordinates are: "<<point2<<std::endl;
    
    Cartesian resultingPoint = point1 + point2;
    std::cout<<"resultingPoint's coordinates are: "<<resultingPoint<<std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: little feedback: prefer not to use the underscore prefix for names in C++. There are some cases, e.g. double underscore or underscore-capital, where it' undefined behavior.

Comment: I am aware of this. In this case there is no undefined behavior. Especially, i never use double underscores. Also, i generally prepend `p` before parameter names to remind me that they are passed by user. I have  done the same in this case. Check out the edit even though it(the edit) was not needed in this case.